# Attach Debugger to Android process button is not showing dialog window

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-debug

Clicking on `Attach Debugger to Android process` button is not showing dialog window to select android process. Nothing happens

what I've tried so far:

- kill adb and restart it
- restart device
- try on new devices
- restart laptop
- invalidate cache

what's causing this bug?

It is working fine with other projects.

Answer (score 0):

so finally fixed the issue. There was some random error notification popped up and this is the error:

> java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/amanbansal/Documents/Projects//benchmark/macro/build/intermediates/apk_ide_redirect_file/debug/../../../outputs/apk/debug/output-metadata.json (No such file or directory)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:885)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:814)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:751)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:441)
> at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:825)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:440)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
> at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:492)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

deleted the build folder from the module.